# Execute actions (actions module not rules module) programatically

Tags: 8, plugins, actions

How can an action from the actions module be executed programatically? In D7 there was actions_do() but in D8 actions are plugins or configuration entities according to https://www.drupal.org/node/2020549.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should inject the plugin manager as a service if possible, but for a plugin (code) based action:

```
$manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.action');
$action = $manager->createInstance('action_plugin_id')
$action->execute();
```

Or if it's an advanced action, it's a config entity, so load and execute it that way:

```
$action = \Drupal\system\Entity\Action::load($action_id);
$action->execute();
```

Again if DI is an option, inject the entity type manager service and use that to load the action instead.

Comment: It's an advanced action I would like to execute that has configuration. It means I created an advanced action in config/system/actions. As far as I understand 'action_plugin_id' does not specify this advanced action?

Comment: All plugin instances (including actions) have an ID, it'll be in the name of the config file

Comment: I misunderstood @Sebastian, sorry, I thought you meant you'd added it via configuration. I edited the answer to cover your use case